# Searching a List of a List with List

Tags: haskell

I'm having a bit of trouble with some of list to list of a list of strings comprehension. In the code below, I have a list of list of strings called dictionary (which we can consider global for our purposes) and a list of search strings, which is the input. The code is here:

```
simpleSearch :: [String] -> [[String]]
simpleSearch a = [z | z <- dictionary, elem a z]
```

Earlier I tried to create a search as described above that is based on the zipWith code to do the   search, but no dice:

```
search' :: [a] -> [[a]] -> [[a]]  
search' _ [] = []
search' [] _ = []
search' (x:xs) (y:ys)   
    | elem x y  = x : search' x ys  
    | otherwise = search' xs ys
```

What I'm trying to do is search the double list, 'dictionary'/'z' for each string in list 'a' and then return the full list that contains the string. So dictionary might contains something like [["b", "c"], ["d", "e"], ["f", "g"]] and list 'a' might contain ["b", "d"] and that I would get back [["b", "c"], ["d","e"]].
Thank you!

Comment: So, what exactly is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem is here:

```
...
  | elem x y  = x : search' x ys
  | otherwise = search' xs ys
```

In the first case you are calling `search'` with `x` and in the second case with `xs`. But `x` and `xs` have different types - `xs`is a list of `x`.

You need to structure the iteration like this:

```
search :: Eq a => [a] -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
search [] _ = []
search (x:xs) ys = (go x ys) ++ search xs ys
```

where `go` is a helper function of type `go :: Eq a => a -> [[a]] -> [[a]]`

The `go` function is responsible for finding all of the lists containing just `x`. The `search` function is responsibile for iterating over the list `xs` and concatenating the results of all of the `go` calls.